# How to write an Idris function that accepts a Vect of length less than 3

Tags: idris, dependent-type

Idris 1.2.0. I tried to automatically find a proof that the length of the vector is less than 3.

```
f : {n : Nat} -> {auto prf: n < 3 = True} -> Vect n a -> ()
f v = ()

f' : {n : Nat} -> {auto prf: isJust (natToFin n 3) = True} -> Vect n a -> ()
f' v = ()
```

Both of these typecheck, and work with `f {n=2} [1, 2}` and even `f (the (Vect 2 Nat) [1, 2])` but when I call it like `f [1, 2]`, I get

```
When checking argument x to constructor Data.Vect.:::
    No such variable len
```

I also tried another way:

```
g : {x : Fin 3} -> Vect (finToNat x) a -> ()
g v = ()
```

This works with `g {x=2} [1, 2]` too, but again fails with `g [1, 2]`

```
When checking an application of function Main.g:
    Type mismatch between
            Vect 2 Integer (Type of [1, 2])
    and
            Vect (finToNat x) Integer (Expected type)

    Specifically:
            Type mismatch between
                    2
            and
                    finToNat x
```

Ok, I guess these two expressions don't reduce to the same canonical form when `x` is unknown.

I don't understand the first error. I suspect it has something to do with [] syntax overloading. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idris does not try to inverse the (injective) function `finToNat` to guess the value for `x` when trying to solve the unification problem `finToNat x = 2`. So it simply gets stuck.

On a more general level rather than pushing computations in the type or proof search in the implicit arguments, I would represent bounded vectors by either:

```
record BoundedVec (n : Nat) (a : Type) where
  size : Nat
  less : LTE size n
  vect : Vect size a
```

Or, following [Agda's standard library](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.BoundedVec.Inefficient.html)

```
data BoundedVec : (n : Nat) -> (a : Type) -> Type where
  Nil  : BoundedVec n a
  Cons : a -> BoundedVec n a -> BoundedVec (S n) a
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that is a robust approach, aside from the need to convert. Still: why did the first two examples fail? What's with the error about `len`? Btw with `{auto prf: LTE n 3}`, `f [1]` works but `f [1, 2]` does not (mismatch btw `S` and `Z`).

Comment: Looks like Idris has bounded lists too, in the `contrib` package: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Data/BoundedList.idr#L9

Comment: A piece of advice: just forget about `auto`. Generally speaking, try to manipulate solid evidence (e.g. directly a `BoundedVec`) rather than relying on ad-hoc proof search. This will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [gallais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727667/gallais) for the insight. Here's a complete example:

```
-- idris -p contrib

import Data.BoundedList
import Data.Vect

-- a function that takes a list of at most 3 elements
f : BoundedList 3 a -> ()
f xs = ()

-- a shorter vector
v : Vect 2 Int
v = [1, 2]

-- convert the vector to a bounded list and weaken the bound
bounded : BoundedList 3 Int
bounded = weaken $ fromList $ toList v

-- call the function
answer : ()
answer = f bounded
```

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a `fromVect : Vect n a -> BoundedList n a` function. Probably worth sending a PR adding it.